# What kind of Critical Points are the ones in the Picture?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I am trying to find all local Maxima and Minima of the function $f(x,y):=xy^2 \cdot exp(-x^2-y^2)$.

I found most already, however I found the set $ \{x=x, \ y=0\} $. When calculating the eigenvalues of the *Hessian* I get one equal to $0$ so no statement is possible with the method. However its clear the points on that line (red line) are critical:
[image: Plot of function]

I have two questions:

How are these points called (so far I only know max. min. and saddle points)?

How to show that they are whatever they are called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can classify all critical points in one dimension. They are either a minimum, a maximum or a saddle point. But in higher dimension it is not so easy and there are no names for all the cases, which can appear. Therefore we just name a point, where the gradient of the function is zero a critical point and a critical point is an extremum or it isn't. For non-degenerated critical points where the Hessian neither have zero as an eigenvalue nor is zero an accumulation point of the eigenvalues are a classification if the number of positive eigenvalues of the Hessian is finite. In that case we define the Morse index of a critical value as the number of positive eigenvalue wrt their algebraic multiplicity. A critical point with Morse index 0 is therefore a minimum. In $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a critical point with Morse index $n$ a maximum. And you see that there are $n-1$ more different critical points, but they have no name. They are just characterized by their Morse index.

Answer (score 0):

note that $$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}};-1\right)$$ and $$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}};1\right)$$ are local maxima
and $$\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}};-1\right)$$ and $$\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}};1\right)$$ are local minima

Comment: Yes, I already found them, but I wanted to know what happens with the points on the red line, since they are no maxima or minima, but nevertheless critical points.

Comment: And no saddle points either, I think

Comment: Or does this somehow relate to what the points on the line actually are? If so I do not get it..

Comment: you can also consider your function on the line $y=x$

Comment: Ah I see, this helped me.